# Counting existing permutations in R

Tags: r, algorithm, permutation

I have a large dataset with columns IDNum, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6. The variables are boolean with value either 0 or 1. Each row could be one of 64 different possible permutations. I would like to count the number of rows corresponding to each permutation present. Is there an efficient way to write this in R?

Comment: Its not permutation, its variation. See [this chart](http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html). With that analogy: "How many numbers of 6 digits can you make with 2 digits 0,1?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` can do this.  Here's a shorter example:

```
r <- function() rbinom(10, 1, .5)
d <- data.frame(IDNum=1:10, Var1=r(), Var2=r())
d
   IDNum Var1 Var2
1      1    0    1
2      2    0    1
3      3    0    0
4      4    1    0
5      5    1    1
6      6    0    0
7      7    1    1
8      8    1    0
9      9    0    1
10    10    0    1
```

Now to count the number of each combination:

```
> aggregate(d$IDNum, d[-1], FUN=length)
  Var1 Var2 x
1    0    0 2
2    1    0 2
3    0    1 4
4    1    1 2
```

The values in `d$IDNum` aren't actually used here, but something must be passed to the `length` function.  The values in `d$IDNum` for each combination are passed to `length` to get the count.

Comment: Two very good solutions, thank you!. I am going with #1 because it does exactly what I was hoping, is very simple/compact, and uses aggregate, which I need to add to my vocabulary. The second one was also a good learning opp.

Answer (score 1):

This will give a slightly different result and will list out all the possibilities regardless of whether they are present or not. Example data:

```
nam <- c("IDNum",paste0("Var",1:6))
n <- 5
set.seed(23)
dat <- setNames(data.frame(1:n,replicate(6,sample(0:1,n,replace=TRUE))),nam)


#  IDNum Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
#1     1    1    0    1    0    1    1
#2     2    0    1    1    1    0    1
#3     3    0    1    0    1    0    1
#4     4    1    1    0    1    1    0
#5     5    1    1    1    1    0    1
```

Count em up:

```
data.frame(table(dat[-1]))

#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Freq
#1     0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#...
#28    1    1    0    1    1    0    1
#...
#43    0    1    0    1    0    1    1
#...
#47    0    1    1    1    0    1    1
#48    1    1    1    1    0    1    1
#...
#54    1    0    1    0    1    1    1
#...
#64    1    1    1    1    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well using the count function in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

r <- function() rbinom(10, 1, .5)
d <- data.frame(IDNum=1:10, Var1=r(), Var2=r())
d

d %>% count(Var1, Var2)
```

Output:

```
Var1 Var2 n
1    0    0 3
2    0    1 3
3    1    0 1
4    1    1 3
```