# Perform analysis on the results of aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

```
  temp <- aggregate( .~ groupbycolumn, data = df[numCols],FUN=function(x) c(MED =median(x), SD=sd(x)))
```

I have used the aggregate function on data frame df to calculate the median and sd of certain columns in the dataframe.

I want to use the median and sd columns for further analysis.

When i try:

```
temp$med
```

I get the result as NULL. Is there a work around for this? I want to use the median and sd columns for further analysis

Comment: Names are case sensitive. Try `temp$MED`

Comment: I tried everything. if we check names(temp) then we dont even those median and sd columns.

Comment: I tried using summaryBy and I believe that may be the solution for this problem

Comment: I see. You will need to give an example of your data. At the moment the problem is not reproducible. Generally the aggregate function will label the column as `col1.MED`, `col2.MED` etc.

Comment: If you want to use an external package, use `data.table` or `dplyr`. Aggregate is very inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `$` on `aggregate` because in your example, the result is delivered by grouped columns.  Since you're applying two functions, you need to use the column index like you would a matrix.  Here's an example

```
> myfuns <- function(x) c(MED = median(x), SD = sd(x))
> ( ag <- aggregate(. ~ cyl, data = mtcars[1:3], FUN = myfuns) )
#   cyl   mpg.MED    mpg.SD  disp.MED   disp.SD
# 1   4 26.000000  4.509828 108.00000  26.87159
# 2   6 19.700000  1.453567 167.60000  41.56246
# 3   8 15.200000  2.560048 350.50000  67.77132
```

Here, I query only one index value, but get two columns in the result.  This is due to the `myfuns` result.  It's a named vector of length two.  The correct names show up now, although you still won't be able to use the `$` operator because it doesn't operate on matrices.

```
> ag[,2]
#       MED       SD
# [1,] 26.0 4.509828
# [2,] 19.7 1.453567
# [3,] 15.2 2.560048
```

I saw your comment about `summaryBy`, and yes it does return a named list, so subsetting with `$` is possible

```
> ( sb <- summaryBy(. ~ cyl, data = mtcars[1:3], FUN = myfuns) )
#   cyl mpg.MED   mpg.SD disp.MED  disp.SD
# 1   4    26.0 4.509828    108.0 26.87159
# 2   6    19.7 1.453567    167.6 41.56246
# 3   8    15.2 2.560048    350.5 67.77132
> sb$mpg.MED
# [1] 26.0 19.7 15.2
> as.list(sb)
# $cyl
# [1] 4 6 8
#
# $mpg.MED
# [1] 26.0 19.7 15.2
# 
# $mpg.SD
# [1] 4.509828 1.453567 2.560048
#
# $disp.MED
# [1] 108.0 167.6 350.5
#  
# $disp.SD
# [1] 26.87159 41.56246 67.77132
```

Comment: Ah.... the old matrix result from `aggregate`. That's the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24926410/496803) this month.

Comment: Haha, well I'd definitely call that a duplicate

Comment: A `do.call(data.frame, ...)` would flatten that out for the OP and let them access the columns the way they are accustomed to doing.

Comment: I just printed it like that to display the names.